# Concatenate multiple commands and write them in one line to a log file

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm really new to Linux/Ubuntu.
I want to log multiple information out of a bash script to a log file, for example the systems current timestamp, some text, and the systems hostname. I tried something like:

```
date && echo " - Hostname: " && hostname > install.log
```

The line in my log file finally should look like this:

```
Mon Nov  2 18:06:21 CET 2015 - Hostname: 001MySystem
```

Any solution for this? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "$(date) - Hostname: $(hostname)" > install.log
```

Comment: ty! exactly what I was looking for.